# Complex mysql query (getting results from results)

Tags: mysql

I've inherited an oddly programmed database, and am having trouble with a complex query. At it is least for me.

In one table I have four fields:

```
    app_id - question - answer - user
    as4d1a - date_com -  ***   - 421 
    as4d1a - status   -   0    - 421 
    as4d1a - date_com -  ***   - 428 
    as4d1a - status   -   0    - 428 
    as4d1a - date_com -  ***   - 474 
    as4d1a - date_com -  ***   - 511
```

From this one table I need to run the query below which will return many unique users:

```
    SELECT user 
    WHERE  question = 'date_completed'
```

.. and for each of these users I then need to run something like the query below

```
    SELECT * 
    WHERE  question = status 
    AND    answer = 0
```

But in such a way that I can use `mysql_num_rows` and possibly do something with each value later. But I mainly need a `count`.

Can anyone help? I've been searching, but don't even know whether I need a `JOIN` or not since all this stuff's in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    table a
INNER JOIN
    table b ON a.user = b.user AND b.question = 'date_completed'
WHERE
    a.question = 'status'
    AND a.answer = 0
```

Comment: that did it, thanks - i know i need to study these joins... thanks much